# Pandas replace not replacing the whole string

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm going through a text and I need to replace a bunch of CIDs (characters that were not readable when I scraped them). I need to replace every "cid:###" with the correct character. The issue that I'm currently running into is that some CIDs are wrapped around in `<s></s>` and there is no space between `<s>(cid:131)</s>` and the next word.

So, when I use replace, it doesn't work when I try to replace `<s>(cid:131)</s>` to ▪. When I try to replace cid:131 with ▪, I get `<s>▪</s>`. I'm trying to get rid of the `<s></s>` for this specific case (`<s></s>` is found in other places in the document and I don't want to replace those).

Doesn't change anything:

```
csv_of_table = csv_of_table.replace('<s>(cid:131)</s>', '▪', regex=True)
```

Only changes the part with cid:131:

```
csv_of_table = csv_of_table.replace('cid:131', '▪', regex=True)
```

Comment: Not sure if all your ` CID:###` need to be replaced by `▪` (seems unlikely). But you could make sure to first replace all `<s>`  and `</s>` that are around those CID's. For example through: `<s>(?=cid:\d{3})|(?<=cid:\d{3})<\/s>`. Then after, you can run whatever operation you had going to replace those CID's.

Comment: No, I have a list of CIDs I'm going through across several different fonts and characters. This is one of the only ones with the ```<s></s>``` tags, though. Let me try that.

Comment: Let me know how it went, just noticed the paranthesis. You might want to replace the suggested pattern by: `<s>(?=\(cid:\d{3})|(?<=\(cid:\d{3}\))<\/s>` to get it to work.

Comment: I was able to make it work with @Ben Pap's solution (though I replaced \d with 131.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ? quantifier to signify that a group can appear 0 or multiple times.

```
csv_of_table = csv_of_table.replace("(<s>\()?cid:\d+(\)<\/s>)?", "▪", regex = True)
```

Comment: Are you saying that ? would take into account things like: ```<s><s>cid:131</s></s>```? Because this is not my issue, unfortunately. And I just tried it and it only changes cid:131 to ▪. Thanks for helping, though!

Comment: hmm, it should work, take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/fi2KCk/2 It fully matches both cases. Can we get the actual text from csv_of_table?

Comment: Hmm. Here's an example: <s>(cid:131)</s>Marine Environment

Comment: I noticed that I forgot to add the parentheses in my initial example! It's still not working, though.

Comment: OP mentioned he does **not** want to replace just any CID by `"▪"`. I guess if your suggestion ends up working thats exactly what it will do.

Comment: The `(` actually make a world of difference, especially with regex! My edit should fix this

Comment: It worked! @BenPap I should have known you can't just use parentheses like (cid:###) with regex... Thank you!

Comment: I replaced \d with 131 since I need the rest of the CIDs to be replaced by something else!